# How to determine the Destination View Controller class correctly

Tags: ios, ios6, uistoryboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to check the class of the destination view controller correctly, but cannot figure how to do this.

I have tried the following:

```
if (segue.destinationViewController == NSStringFromClass([MESSelectWordViewController class])) {
```

But this does not work as expected, it does not result correctly. `MESSelectWordViewController` is my view controller class that I am passing information to within `prepareForSegue` method. However, I only need this information to be passed on this specific segue as opposed to any others. Therefore I am doing the above if to pass the information if correct.

What is the correct way to accomplish this, surely there is a better route as opposed to `NSString@"MESSelectWordViewController` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
 if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[MESSelectWordViewController class]]) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could check if

```
[segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[MESSelectWordViewController class]];
```